# How do I use the Ruby twitter gem to get a list of followers for a given ID/handle?

Tags: ruby, twitter-gem

I want to use v5.0 of the Twitter gem, and I can't figure out the documentation to understand how to get a list of followers, given a handle.

It looks like previous versions had a method that looked something like `Twitter.follower_ids('ID to lookup')`, but that doesn't work any more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if there's some easier way to navigate the RDoc documentation but I had to first root around in the code, to notice the RDoc comments, to then realize that [this is the page](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/twitter/Twitter/REST/FriendsAndFollowers#followers-instance_method) which documents some of the behavior I wanted.

`# configure client with secrets and access keys
client.followers 'screen_name_of_interest'`

This returns a certain number of followers - but I still can't figure out how to figure out how many followers, and how to use cursors to retrieve more.

Comment: Looks like I actually spent a lot of time on this earlier and commented on [this gist that the gem author wrote](https://gist.github.com/sferik/9630519)...